# SASS variables import

Tags: css, variables, sass

I am having a bit of an issue with SASS's variables import.

Here is my styles.scss where all the imports are:

```
/************************************ PARTIALS */
@import 'partials/reset';
@import 'partials/clearfix';
@import 'partials/variables';
@import 'partials/mixins';
@import 'partials/main';
@import 'partials/navOverlay';
@import 'partials/mediaQueries';
```

My main CSS is in _main.scss (@import 'partials/main';) which is after the _variables.scss (@import 'partials/variables';) , but when I use a variable from _variables.scss in _main.scss I get an error saying that the variable I am using is not declared?

Where am I doing it wrong? What is the scope of SASS's variables, where do I need to put them?

Comment: So far, my experience with SASS imports taught me that it is always best to include the extension (.scss) on an import. Tends to fix some issues, you might try that.

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import partials/variables to every SASS file where you use this variables. thus you need import partials/variables to partials/main but not to styles.scss. You also should import partials/variables to every sass file where you use these variables.

Comment: So the only way for the _main.scss to reach for _variables.scss is including it within the _main.scss , meaning that it CAN NOT reach it from the styles.scss imports?

Comment: This is incorrect. You can absolutely structure your files in the way described by the OP. Take [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss#L8) for example. Importing variable files into all your partials is not the way to go.